# Microsoft SQL Server one vs 2 separated tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am about to make some logic for my current project and I read so many opinions for the answer regarding multiple vs single table.

My specific question is say I have a `category` which has `items`, while I write this question it's only seem logic that I will have

`Categories` table

```
[id], [name], maybe comments/Description
```

Side note: actually I prefer to leave `CategoryID` "free" and add a `RowIndex` column as identity for most of my tables.

And for each id I will have

`Items` table

- `[categoryID]` reference to its catagory,
- `[itemID]`, `[content]`, ...rest item's properties...

but is it not unnecessary to the point I even added `[name]` which I could live without added for convenience, and also for just in case `[comments]`. It seems that I could easy get rid of `Categories` table.

What are the pros and cons if any ?

Comment: Well, the main issue I see here is one of fundamental misunderstanding what this site is for. It is not a "write me a detailed analysis about a tool I use and do not understand". Pro and Con listing is subjective and way too broad.

Comment: @TomTom in my case it's a mini cms partial content manger semi content manager , so when i think of it, it might be more agile having separated index for categories where i could put bit column for online/active or down, so it will be an easy job for the server and application that's act appon this specific record id-on/of-`bit` rather  ok lets go and mark all items of this category with `0`

Comment: Well, having an explicit `Categories` table gives you the ability to specify the conclusive list of all **valid** categories - you can only add an item, if one of those valid categories is picked (as the foreign key column value). This prevents data chaos and that alone is **more than enough** for me to advocate always having lookup tables for each "thing" that you want to have an inclusive, complete list of possible values for

Comment: @marc_s while you are writing comment , it was few seconds of after me , thinking exactly this.

Comment: I see no pros for having a single table, only cons.

Answer (score 0):

thinking of this and as @marc_s pointed it out

say you have the same idea , a subject that has child, 
well in this case it's concrete and undisputed: **2 tables**

category - item . factoryProducts- AllproductsTypesTable...

in any case there's better control on the data having an index of the parents objects.